# CRUD over aggregate root using traditional ado.net

Tags: c#, ado.net, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

Can anyone show me simple CRUD statements for aggregate root using traditional ado.net?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is written on the assumption that a GUID or some non-database generated primary key is used)
Also alot of boiler code such as connection management etc... should be moved to a base class for Repository.
If Order is the aggregate root, one possibly should make OrderLineRepo private to the assembly

```
public class OrderRepository : Repository

{
    public void Save(Order order)
    {
        if(order.IsDirty)
        {
                    //sets up connection if required, command and sql
            ICommand command = BuildCommandForSave(order);  
            command.Execute();
            OrderLineRepository orderLineRepo = GetOrderLineRepo();
            foreach(OrderLine line in order.OrderLines)
            {
                orderLineRepo.Save(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I'd stress that this is really a simple naive implementation, and that I'd personally utilize an ORM like nHibernate for my persistence if doing DDD as the requirements for a good well tested persistence layer are non-trivial

Also this assumes that the IsDirty function takes children into account - we would also require a means to see if the order is new/edited, not just dirty

Comment: As a side point one will often utilze a default unsaved ID value - so when save is called we can look at this ID value and determine if the object is new/updated

Comment: Re: "the requirements for a good well tested persistence layer are non-trivial". In some cases developing an ADO.net persistence layer makes sense. For projects involving significant reporting, pure ADO.Net or a micro-orm is the recommended approach for the "thin read models" used in the query side of CQRS. So if you need to use ADO.Net for the query side of things, it is not so much of a stretch to use ADO.net for the command side as well, especially if a legacy database is involved that does not easily map to model classes. Your answer helped me combine an ADO.Net approach with DDD.